# How to change the order of coefficients in a coefficient plot in R (package dotwhisker)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, coefficients

Here is some sample code from the official package documentation.

```
#Package preload
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

# run a regression compatible with tidy
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + disp + gear, data = mtcars)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . + hp) # add another predictor

m1_df <- tidy(m1) %>% filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>% mutate(model = "Model 1")
m2_df <- tidy(m2) %>% filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>% mutate(model = "Model 2")

two_models <- rbind(m1_df, m2_df)

dwplot(two_models)
```

which produces this:

[image: coefficient plot]

The most logical order inside the plot would be to have the coefficients from model 1 above model 2. In any case I would like to know how to control the order of coefficients from distinct models (not the order of the variables themselves). I tried sorting the tidy dataframe with `order` or factorizing the model column with `factor`. Neither of the two work. Any advice would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order of the coefficients by reordering your tidy dataframe. A possible problem might be that the legend order changes as well, but this can be fixed as well.

```
dwplot(arrange(two_models, desc(model))) + 
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("Model 1","Model 2"))
```

[image]